# Real Time Monitoring Architecture for distributed Database

Tags: mysql, sqlite, database-design, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I am building a real time monitoring tool.

Here is the Scenario:

I have multiple nodes(Servers) running there own database (SQL) instance. I want to see the information from those databases on one system. 
So as far as I know there could be two possible solutions:
1. Query each and every Node to get updates form there database
2. Get the data (database) from every node and put it on one system to query just one database.

I would really appreciate if somebody can help me with the pros and cons of both the solution or any other approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do.

For "monitoring", it is generally best to collect data from the monitored systems and store it into a single (third, in your case) database server.  Then munch on that as needed.

In some other situation you might need to immediately `JOIN` the data from the two servers.  This is not easy to do.  See Spider or Federated or FederatedX for ways to do that.

Comment: Thank you.. I preferred the storing data into third server